# pgfplotstable: Highlight rows of a numeric sequence

Tags: lists, pgfplotstable, pgfkeys, pgfmath

I would like to highlight the rows `n*(n+3)/2 = 0, 2, 5, 9, 14, 20, 27, 35,...` 
How could I automate that best way using the term `n*(n+3)/2`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{
highlightrow/.style={
  postproc cell content/.append code={
  \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
   \advance\count0 by0
   \ifnum\count0=#1
          % \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}}
              \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\textbf{##1}}%
    \fi},     },      }


%\def\List{7,9,10}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
highlightrow=0, % works
highlightrow/.list={2,5,9}, % works 
%highlightrow/.list=\List, % works not
]{
A    B     C
0   x     x
1    x     x
2    x     x
3    x     x
4    x     x
5    x     x
6    x     x
7    x     x
8    x     x
9    x     x
10    x     x
11    x     x
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `highlightrow/.list/.expand once=\List`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`handlers/.list` uses `\foreach` to unfold the list:

```
\foreach \pgf@keys@key in{#1}%
```

while `pgffor` handle the list in different ways by checking if there is a leading `\bgroup`:

```
\def\pgffor@@vars@end in{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\bgroup{\pgffor@normal@list}{\pgffor@macro@list}%
}
```

As you see macro list (**unbraced**) is expanded to a normal list (**braced**) first:

```
\def\pgffor@macro@list#1{%
  \expandafter\pgffor@normal@list\expandafter{#1}}
```

So when you write `highlightrow=\List` and expect it to be processed as a **macro list**, but actually `\List` is **braced** and be processed as a **normal list** and then error occurs.

The fast way to fix the problem is what [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) has mentioned in her comment: use `highlightrow/.list/.expand once=\List`.

I provide another way to make it possible to use a *function* to get the row index with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pgfplotstableset{
  highlightrow/.style 2 args={
    postproc cell content/.append code={
      \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=#1
        \pgfkeysalso{@cell content={#2##1}}%
      \fi
    },
  },
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \rowstyle } { O{30} O{#1} m }
  {
    \row_style:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\int_new:N \l__i_int
\int_new:N \l__index_int
\cs_new_protected:Nn \row_style:nnn
  {
    \cs_set:Nn \__parse_expr:n
      {
        \fp_to_int:n { floor(#2) }
      }
    \fp_compare:nT { #1 >= 0 }
      {
        \int_zero:N \l__i_int
        \fp_while_do:nn { \__parse_expr:n { \l__i_int } <= #1 }
          {
            \tl_set:Nx \l_tempa_tl {
              \exp_not:N \pgfplotstableset{
                highlightrow={\__parse_expr:n { \l__i_int }}{ \exp_not:n { #3 } }
              }
            }
            \tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl
            \int_incr:N \l__i_int
          }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\rowstyle[11][#1*(#1 + 3)/2]{\color{red}}
\rowstyle[11][(#1 + 1)*4]{\color{blue}\bfseries}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{
  A  B C
  0  x x
  1  x x
  2  x x
  3  x x
  4  x x
  5  x x
  6  x x
  7  x x
  8  x x
  9  x x
  10 x x
  11 x x
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! `\l_tempa_tl` should probably be `\l_tmpa_tl`.

Answer (score 2):

With the tip `highlightrow/.list/.expand once=\List` 
I use a pgfmath-solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
A    B     C
0   x     x
1    x     x
2    x     x
3    x     x
4    x     x
5    x     x
6    x     x
7    x     x
8    x     x
9    x     x
10    x     x
11    x     x
}{\mytable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Rows{int(\pgfplotsretval-1)}
Rows: \Rows.
% Solution of Rows = n*(n+3)/2
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{int(floor(0.5*(sqrt(8*\Rows+9)-3)))}
Maximal n: \N=N

% List: 
\let\List=\empty% create List
\foreach \n  in {0,...,\N}
{%
\pgfmathparse{int(\n*(\n+3)/2}%  
  \ifx\empty\List{} \xdef\List{\pgfmathresult}%
  \else \xdef\List{\List,\pgfmathresult}%
  \fi
}
List: \List

\pgfplotstableset{
highlightrow/.style={
  postproc cell content/.append code={
  \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
   \advance\count0 by0
   \ifnum\count0=#1
          % \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}}
              \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\color{red}\textbf{##1}}%
    \fi},     },     
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
%highlightrow=0,% 
highlightrow/.list/.expand once=\List,
]{\mytable}
\end{document}a
```